# Is it a good practice to terminate kernel thread with "return" or "do_exit()"?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

My objective is to execute kernel thread from my driver's probe function only ONCE which performs firmware downloading.

Putting up sample code(not actual one) for simplicity,

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/kthread.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

struct task_struct *kthread;


static int thread_func(void* data)
{
    printk("In %s function\n", __func__);
    return 0;
}

static int hello_init(void)
{
    int ret = 0;

    printk("Hello World\n");
    kthread = kthread_run(thread_func,
            NULL, "kthread-test");
    if (IS_ERR(kthread)) {
        ret = PTR_ERR(kthread);
        printk("Unable to run kthread err %d\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    return 0;
}


static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk("Bye World\n");

}
```

I am not using any of following because:

1. `kthread_should_stop()` - used for continuous execution which I do not want
2. `kthread_stop(struct task_struct *thread)` - if included in module exit function, causes kernel panic since thread was already terminated after executing once

Is this a correct approach? if not please suggest

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to ensure that thread has gone away before the module exit function returns. One way to do that is by using a "completion" structure.

The basic idea is to initialize the completion structure before starting the thread, make the thread mark the completion structure as "complete" when it exits, and have the module exit function (or whatever) wait for the completion structure to be marked as complete.

1. **Prerequisites**

   ```
   #include <linux/completion.h>
   ```
2. **Initialize the completion structure**

   If the completion structure variable is statically allocated, it can be initialized in the variable definition using the `DECLARE_COMPLETION` macro:

   ```
   static DECLARE_COMPLETION(thread_done);
   ```

   (There is also a `DECLARE_COMPLETION_ONSTACK` macro for use when the completion structure variable is on the stack.)

   Alternatively, an uninitialized `struct completion` can be defined (for example as a member of a dynamically allocated structure) and initialized subsequently by calling `init_completion(...)`:

   ```
   struct completion thread_done;

   ...

   init_completion(&thread_done);
   ```
3. **Create the thread**

   ```
   kthread = kthread_run(thread_func, NULL, "kthread-test");
   if (IS_ERR(kthread)) {
       complete(&thread_done); /* <-- may or may not be required */
       ret = PTR_ERR(kthread);
       return ret;
   }
   ```

   In the above, if `kthread_run(...)` fails, the completion structure is marked as "complete" in case some code waits for completion later. If it is guaranteed that nothing will wait for completion later, the `complete(&thread_done);` call can be omitted.
4. **Exit the thread**

   Rather than returning from the thread function or calling `do_exit(...)`, the thread should call `complete_and_exit(...)` to mark the thread as "complete":

   ```
   complete_and_exit(&thread_done, 0);
   ```

   Calling `complete_and_exit(...)` is safer than separate calls to `complete(...)` and `do_exit(...)`. With separate calls to `complete(...)` and `do_exit(...)` there is a possibility that the module code will have already been unloaded when `complete(...)` returns, so the thread could execute non-existent or random code. Calling `complete_and_exit(...)` avoids that happening because the function exists outside the module code and never returns.
5. **Ensure the thread has finished**

   To ensure that the thread has finished, call `wait_for_completion(...)`:

   ```
   wait_for_completion(&thread_done);
   ```

   On return, the thread will have either exited already or it is still running in the call to `complete_and_exit(...)` and is about to exit. In either case, it is no longer running any of the module code, so it is safe to continue.